# Numpy Column Stack with Strings?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using `numpy.column_stack` and having problems

```
Input = input('Input: ')

Words = ['First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth','Sixth','Seventh','Eigth','Ninth']
Numbers = [0.5,1,1.25,1.5,2,3,5,10,15]
Stack = np.column_stack((Words, Numbers))
```

What I am hoping to achieve is:

Input: Second
Output: 1

Input: Ninth
Output: 15

Later down the line with this I am hoping to have a secondary file that is editable to define the lists of Words and Numbers into. I don't know if Column Stack is the best way to make this but its the closest thing I could think of?

Comment: What's the result supposed to look like?  Shape, dtype? Your code runs.  What's wrong with the result?

Comment: What are you asking, sorry? Can you rephrase it? What issue are you facing, what is the error message, and what is your expected output?

Comment: @Ian Quah I attempted to rephrase it to be easier to understand, apologies for the spelling and grammatical errors... fervently trying to get this to work XD

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this? Something like a dictionary would work far better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, what you want is to use a dictionary:

```
Words = ['First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth','Sixth','Seventh','Eigth','Ninth']
Numbers = [0.5,1,1.25,1.5,2,3,5,10,15]
Stack = {word:number for (word, number) in zip(Words, Numbers)}

Input = input('Input: ')
try:
    print(Stack[Input])
except KeyError:
    print('Input: {} does not exist'.format(Input))
```

In this example `Stack` is being created as a dictionary using dictionary comprehension with `zip`. You then use the `Input` from the user as a key for the dictionary. If that key is in the dictionary the corresponding value will be printed, otherwise it will print a message indicating the key is not in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You could pair words with numbers using simple list operations:

```
In [283]: Numbers                                                               
Out[283]: [0.5, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15]
In [284]: Numbers[Words.index('Fifth')]                                         
Out[284]: 2
In [285]: Numbers[Words.index('Second')]                                        
Out[285]: 1
In [286]: Numbers[Words.index('Ninth')]                                         
Out[286]: 15
```